# Filter a pcap dump file for a specific time range

Tags: pcap, tcpdump, tshark, editcap

Is there any easy way to create a *pcap file* for the packets related to a specific datetime range maybe using `tshark`, `tcpdump` or another commandline tool?

`tshark -R` with `frame.time` seems promising but I haven't been able to work that out yet...

**EDIT**

The final command:

```
editcap -F libpcap -A "2013-07-20 23:00:00" -B "2013-07-20 23:20:00" input.pcap output.pcap
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

What you need is `editcap`. It's a command-line tool that is part of the Wireshark family.

Check out the man page at http://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/editcap.html.

It takes a pcap file as input, and writes an output one. You may operate on the infile to filter content, for example, with **start-time and end-time**, packet number ranges, snap packet length, adjusting timestamps (!), etc. It's a great tool.